# Let $E = \{2k$| $k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ ; $F = \{l^2$| $l\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Determine $E\cap F$, $E-F$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have attempted to solve these questions on my own but as I have not seen an example of this before I have no idea how to present the answer or if I am even on the right track. Any help or some type of similar example would be great. Thanks in advance.

1. Let $A = \{2^k$| $k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ ; $B = \{l^2$| $l\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

a) Determine $A\cap B$.

b) Determine $A-B$.

2. Let $E = \{2k$| $k\in \mathbb{N}\}$ ; $F = \{l^2$| $l\in \mathbb{N}\}$.

a) Determine $E\cap F$.

b) Determine $E-F$.

Comment: This is identical to the previous time you asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829071/find-difference-and-intersection-between-denumerable-sets#comment3738635_1829071).  My comment is the same as last time.  $A\cap B$ is the set of powers of two which are also perfect squares.  $A\setminus B$ is the set of powers of two which are not perfect squares.  When is a number a perfect square?  How would you **attempt** (*heavy emphasis on* **attempt**) to denote this yourself?

Comment: As for $E$ and $F$, the set $E$ are the even natural numbers.  The set $F$ is the set of perfect squares.  So, $E\cap F$ are the even perfect squares.  $E\setminus F$ are the even numbers which are not perfect squares.

Comment: This can be written in a number of ways, the easiest and most intuitive way of which is literally using what I just said.  $E\setminus F = \{n~:~n\in \Bbb N,~n~\text{is even and is not a perfect square}\}$.  If you prefer to use more symbols than that, it is your choice.  *Be Creative!*

Comment: Thank you for your response.  So for 1. you could simply state $A\cap B$=$\{n:n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n$ is a power of two and is a perfect sqaure$\}$?

Comment: You could, but with symbols might be kinder.  Note that a natural number is a perfect square iff in its prime decomposition, the power of every prime is even.  So, $\{2^k~:~k~\text{is even},~k\in\Bbb N\}$ might be easier to write.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @JMoravitz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.$$A \cap B = \{2^{2m}|m \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
  $$A - B = \{2^{2m+1}|m \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
2. $$E \cap F = \{2^{2m+2}\cdot n^{2}|m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$
   $$E - F = \{2\cdot p^{2n+1} \cdot q|m,q \in \mathbb{N},p~\text{is prime larger  than 2},  p \nmid q\}$$